# How to unlink/remove a directory from a symlink?

Tags: command-line, server, symbolic-link

I'm totally new in commands, generally.

```
lrwxrwxrwx filename-static -> filename.2017
drwxrwxr-x filename.2017.new
```

I want to replace OLD 2017 linked directory with the NEW directory i just uploaded to my server. (the files are in root folder)

Searching the web lead me to the following commands:

```
rm /path/
```

or

```
unlink /path/
```

and then replace with the new file

```
ln /path/
```

I just don't understand what is the exact command?

```
rm ./filename-static/filename.2017 ?
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want the situation to look like? I don't know which directory is "NEW". Which directory and/or symbolic link do you want to remove? Which symbolic links do you want to create or alter?

Comment: Based on the post title and output of `ls`, `filename-static` is a *symbolic link*. (This makes sense; Ubuntu, and most Unix-like OSes, don't allow additional directory hard links to be created with `ln`.) So if the goal is to replace the pointed-to directory, renaming `filename.2017` to `filename.2017.old` and `filename.2017.new` to `filename.2017` does that: the old symlink will point to the new directory, because a symlink holds a path name. I don't really know if that's what you want, though--as @DavidFoerster says, this is rather unclear. Can you **[edit]** this to explain further?

Comment: @EliahKagan: That makes sense. Let's wait for OP's clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You ca either remove the file (link)

```
rm filename-static
```

or decrease the number of links

```
unlink filename-static
```

You can also force relink on this way:

```
ln -sf filename.2017.new filename-static
```

Comment: Though arguably technically correct, this answer is misleading and potentially dangerous, because it describes the effects of `rm filename-static` and `unlink filename-static` as though they are different. Both delete `filename-static`. `unlink` is not limited to removing symlinks; when people assume it is, they risk data loss. (*Both* commands remove a [*hard* link](http://foldoc.org/hard%20link) and decrement an inode's link count. `unlink` merely ["avoids the bells and whistles of the more commonly-used `rm`"](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#unlink-invocation).)

Comment: @EliahKagan, I do not understand you. Every command can be dangerous in UNIX/Linux. Moreover I provide the way to relink the file on the fly (w/o explicitly exec other command)

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way (AFAIK) to change where a link points to.  Instead, you
just remove the old link, then make a new link (with the same name),
pointing to the new target.  (I assume we are talking about symbolic links,
not hard links; hence, you need the "-s".)

```
rm filename-static

ln -s filename.2017.new filename-static
```

--Benjamin